# Python pygame window closing when I add an icon to the title, how would I open the image in PyCharm, its a png

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I was starting to make a game, and when I added the code for the icon to go alongside the title of the window, it just shuts down without errors. how do I add the image to PyCharm? By the way, I am using mac

this is the code that i wrote for the caption and icon:

```
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that as stated on the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) you should enter the full path of the image.

The recommended way would be to make an import of the [os module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) and take advantage of the `os.path.join()` method. Although simply putting your full image path should also work though.

Comment: Do I just add os.path.join() into the same part of the code?, I don't really understand how to put the image path in, using a mac, will there even be icons next to the title? thanks

Comment: You could initially just test with the full path as a string variable (e.g. `icon = pygame.image.load('/my/path/to/spacehip.png')`) (in order to check the full path of a file using Mac OSX you could refer to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/717105/how-to-show-full-path-of-a-file-including-the-full-filename-in-mac-osx-terminal/1533160)). If these works you could proceed to use the `os.path.join()` method, check [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-join-method/) as it might give you further advise as how to use this method.